# Installing custom Android Froyo kernel for Samsung Tablet GT-P7510?

Tags: android, android-source

I've been building permission-handling extensions to the java middleware on a fork of the Froyo kernel. Everything works in the emulator and I'm ready to try it on the tablet. But there seem to be no comprehensible instructions for installing custom kernels (what's a "recovery"? An "update"?), or else point you to market roms (mine is custom, not on the market), or are explicitly flagged as "unreliable".

To be clear, I have a custom kernel+middleware source directory that builds and runs in the emulator without problem. This is probably a generic kernel as I've seen no mention of Samsung tablets in there.

Should I be using Android 2.2 as the build target in Eclipse, or the Samsung Tab 2.2 target? Or is eclipse even relevant when doing a kernel build (probably not). What happens if I pick the wrong one or screw up elsewhere? And most of all, how to recover if I make a wrong choice?

The build produces several .img files but the boot loader seems to want a .zip file. Do I build this by hand, or what?

Do clear and reliable instructions exist for this? A recipe would be nice but what I really need is a clear mental model.

Comment: Just found https://opensource.samsung.com/index.jsp;jsessionid=F2EEE22FEC6156B14199E4DF229328D4 on the Samsung OpenSource site and am guessing inserting my extensions into GT-7510_HKTW_OpenSource.zip should be where I should start. Is this right?

Comment: Don't see any way to connect the samsung and android folders or their outputs.